# Connecting .NET named pipes over a network

Tags: c#, network-programming, named-pipes

I have used named pipes to communicate between processes locally and now I am trying to connect over a network to another computer. As far as I understood, the only thing I need to change is the NamedPipeClientStream constructor from

```
NamedPipeClientStream(".", "MyPipe", PipeDirection.InOut,PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
```

to

```
NamedPipeClientStream("xxx.xxx.xxx.xx", "MyPipe" + _name, PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
```

So I did that but I keep getting a System.IO.IOException telling me that the network adress is unreachable (don't know the exact english message, my OS is in german).

I know that similar questions have been asked before and the solutions I found were:

- Windows firewall blocks pipes -> I disabled firewall on both computers
- LanmanWorkstation and LanmanServer have to be running -> I confirmed, both are running on both computers
- A pipe filter might block the pipes -> I used [this](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/help/925890/how-to-use-named-pipe-filters-in-windows-xp-sp2,-in-windows-server-2003-sp1,-and-in-later-versions-of-these-operating-systems) guide to confirm that there is no filter enabled and then also tried setting the "PipeFirewallActive" value to 0.
- I also made sure the connection works by pinging my other computer
  [It's german but I hope you can still tell what is meant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfFHd.png)

None of these fixed my problem unfortunatly. I am an absolute noob when it comes to networks so something as simple as the wrong IP adress might be a mistake I make, but the named pipe implementation works locally, so that shouldn't be the problem.

If you need any more information, I'll provide it. I just don't know what else to add.

Comment: Have you tried to ping from one machine to the other? Just to verify the address is reachable.

Comment: Edited question with screenshot results